# How to use multiple document.getElementById's?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, getelementbyid, var

I have a problem with html and js. I don't know why I can only use the first document.getElementById that is on top.

JavaScript.js

```
var one = "sentence"
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = one;

var two = "sentence sentence"
document.getElementById("text_2").innerHTML = two;

var three = "sentence sentence sentence"
document.getElementById("text_3").innerHTML = three;
```

webpage.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="text"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

When using div id="text_2" or div id="text_3", nothing will come up on the output. Only the document.getElementById that is on top in the js file can be seen on the webpage. So I gues i cannot use multiple getElementById's but I don't know a other way yet. What to do?

Thank you

Comment: You cant retrieve a non exisistant element by ID

Comment: .. because in your HTML there is only *one* element with the `id` of 'text'

Comment: Are you missing html code here? I can't see elements with ids 'text_2' and 'text_3'

Comment: There's no reason you can't use multiple `document.getElementById` calls. Have you checked the console? One of your other statements is throwing an exception as the DOM element you're looking for doesn't exist (yet you're setting `innerHTML` anyway). Use null checking.

Comment: If you change the ID of your one and only DIV to "text_2", the first `getElementById()` will fail, because you try to access `innerHTML` of a non existent element ("text").

Comment: Thats because you have no elements with classes

Comment: Maybe you should explain, what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for all the effort people. What I want is that sometimes I need just need "text" and another time text_2 and so the same for text_3.

Comment: What condition does one appear

Comment: It's solved! Thank you for all the troubles. The support here is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sentence1 = 'sentence',
    sentence2 = 'sentence two',
    sentence3 = 'sentence three',
    el1 = document.getElementById('text'),
    el2 = document.getElementById('text_2'),
    el3 = document.getElementById('text_3');

if (el1) {
    el1.innerHTML = sentence1;
}

if (el2) {
    el2.innerHTML = sentence2;
}

if (el3) {
    el3.innerHTML = sentence3;
}
```

Comment: +1 Yup totally answers the question, when element exists add content

Answer (score 0):

> What I want is that sometimes I need just need "text" and another time text_2 and so the same for text_3.

This is easy enough, you just put whichever one you want in a variable that you can pass to `getElementById`. Something like:

```
var elementId;
if (conditionForText) {
    elementId = "text";
} 
else if (conditionForText2) {
    elementId = "text_2"
}
else if (conditionForText3) {
    elementId = "text_3"
}
// Note: you might want to handle the case where none of the above conditions 
// evaluate to true

document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = someText
```

It's not really clear if the element you want to pick is supposed to get the same text or not, but if you have several id's with several different strings that need to be set, you could map them with an object:

```
var elementsAndStrings = {
    text : "sentence one",
    text_2 : "sentence two",
    text_3 : "sentence three"
};
```

and now you could do something like:

```
document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = elementsAndStrings[elementId];
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="text">Text1</div>
<div class="text">Text2</div>
<div class="text">Text3</div>
<div class="text">Text4</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function getElementByClass (className, parent) {
  parent || (parent = document);
  var descendants= parent.getElementsByTagName('*'), i=-1, e, result=[];
  while (e=descendants[++i]) {
    ((' '+(e['class']||e.className)+' ').indexOf(' '+className+' ') > -1) && result.push(e);
  }
  return result;
}
texts= getElementByClass("text");
var txtVal="";
for (i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
    txtVal += texts[i].innerHTML  + ", ";
}
alert (txtVal);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/7xadr3k8/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/mt78j5m0/

```
<div id="text_1"></div>
<div id="text_2"></div>
<div id="text_3"></div>

var text = {};

text.text_1 = "One";
text.text_2 = "Two";
text.text_3 = "Three";

var divs = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='text']");

for (var div of divs) {
    div.innerHTML = text[div.id];
}
```

Comment: IE, Safari and Opera do not support `for...of` loops

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
const elements = [
  "id1",
  "id2"
].map(document.getElementById);
```